# Given a closed subspace $Y$ of a Banach space $X$, $\mathrm{dim}(X/Y)' = \mathrm{dim}(X/Y)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading Peter D. Lax's functional analysis and have been stuck on his proof for the following theorem:

**Theorem**. Let $C:X\rightarrow X$ be a compact map, and $T=I-C$. Then $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker}(T')) = \mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker}(T))$.

The idea is to use the fact that $\mathrm{Im}{(T)}$ is closed. But in the first step he says for any closed subspace $R$ of $X$, 
$$
\mathrm{dim}{R^\perp}=\mathrm{dim}{(X/R)'}=\mathrm{dim}{(X/R)}=\mathrm{codim}{R}
$$
where $R^\perp$ is the annihilator of $R$. The first equality is trivial while I can't see why the second equality $\mathrm{dim}{(X/R)'}=\mathrm{dim}{(X/R)}$ holds. I can only prove it when $X$ is reflexive, while here we don't have such condition. Can anyone hint on the proof? Many thanks for any help:-)

Comment: It's true if $\dim (X/R) < \infty$, and that's the case we need. It's not true for arbitrary closed subspaces of arbitrary Banach spaces.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, right! Thanks a lot!